# IBActions aren't in File's Owner?

Tags: xcode, uibutton, ibaction

For some reason my IBActions declared in the code aren't in my File's Owner. I've been looking at this for an hour and I can't seem to figure it out.

There's probably a really simple explanation for this. I am probably going to feel dumb. Thanks in advance!

Below is my code.

RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Sqlite.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
Sqlite *database;
NSTimer *myTimer;
UITextView *myTextField;

}

- (IBAction)addAlbum;

@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UILabel *detailTextLabel;

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "TableViewAppDelegate.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

 // If a user adds a photo album
 - (IBAction)addAlbum {

SecondViewController *screen = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
[screen release];

}
```

They do show up in the First Responder, however when I link them they do not work. Thanks!

Edit: I want to use these actions in a different XIB (MainWindow.XIB). I have tried adding my actions in each of the .h's files but none are showing up in my MainWindow.XIB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your **RootViewController.h** has been saved.

Open your **RootViewController.xib** and select File's Owner.

Make sure your RootViewController is selected as the Class in the identity tab.

On the connections tab, you should be able to verify your IBActions.